# Data Dog: parse logs and create dashboards like SUMO

Tags: parsing, logging, datadog

During years I used to work with SUMO. I used to do things like:

```
_sourceCategory=apache 
| parse "GET * " as url 
| count by url
```

And from there you would add time slices, to count on time basis. And then you could also integrate the results with some nice charts like time series, pie chart. All within seconds.

Now, I forced to use DataDog. Imagine you have errors like:

```
Error in house    
Error in car
Error in street
Error in house
Error in house
Error in car
Error in house
Error in street
```

I would like to count errors by place. In this case:

```
PLACE | COUNT
-------------
house |   4
car   |   2
street|   2
```

Well I can't do it with Data Dog. I hate it. I read about Pipeline, Processors, Metrics. I can't believe this is so difficult compared with SUMO.

I have a Pipeline, who parses my logs. Then I can see all the fields being parsed. But how can I create a metric from there? My fields are strings, so I can't "measure" them. I just need to count how many "house" errors happened. And so on with some other strings.